# Data coming Null even when join query is having values in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a dependency Table Sellars which is having the City ID only. But while showing the sellars I need to show the Sellar country, state. I have written the join query it is returning rest of the sellar details except country,city and state as null. I haven't kept any relation like @manytoOne as it will also show the zipcode list under the city as there is a relation.

```
@Entity(name = "tbl_sellars")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Sellars extends CommonEntity {
    
    @Column(name = "sellarName")
    String sellarName;
    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "fk_city_id")   // this contains the city Id
    String fk_city_id;
    
    @Transient             //Kept these variable Transient as I Don't need these in Entity
    String country;
    @Transient
    @JsonProperty
    String state;
    @Transient
    @JsonProperty
    String cityName;
}


@Entity(name= "tbl_city")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class City extends CommonEntity {
    
    String cityName;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_state_id")
    private State state;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_city_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<ZipCode> zipcodes;
}

@Repository
public interface SellarsRepository extends JpaRepository<Sellars, Long>{
      @Query(value = "SELECT u.*, c.country, s.state,ci.cityName" +
      " FROM tbl_sellars u" + " JOIN tbl_city ci ON u.fk_city_id = ci.id" +
      " JOIN tbl_state s ON ci.fk_state_id = s.id" +
      " JOIN tbl_country c ON s.fk_country_id = c.id", nativeQuery = true)
      List<Sellars> getAllSellarsWithRegion();
}
```

Json Returned like

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "sellarName": "Avik ray",
    "country": null,
    "state": null,
    "cityName": null
  }
]
```

Comment: OT, but what is a "sellar"?

Comment: Sellars is a table having the city id. and city is having child zipcodes. city's parent is state -> country @g00se

Comment: Do you mean 'seller'?

Comment: The fields are `@Transient` thus they are ignored, regardless of the fact if they are in the result or not. Create a DTO and map the result to that instead of your entity.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have created the DTO class. still it is null as sellars don't have those country,state fields. I have added those country ,state, city in DTO class

Comment: You need to put the DTO in the query and let JPA create it, you shouldn't use the entity to map to a dto.

Comment: @M.Deinum let me give a try

Answer (score 1):

As your attributes are annotated with `@Transient` they will not be handled by Hibernate and are therefore null

Answer (score 1):

`@Transient` annotation is used to mark a field to be transient for the mapping framework, which means the field marked with `@Transient` is ignored by mapping framework and the field not mapped to any database column (in RDBMS) or Document property (in NOSQL). Thus the property will not be persisted to data store.

Source: https://javabydeveloper.com/using-transient-in-spring-boot-examples/